# PHP find local time by Time Zone

Tags: php

Example, I have time zone is : "Europe/London" or "America/Los_Angeles"

In Perl, I can look up for Local Time by:

```
use DateTime;
use DateTime::TimeZone;

$timeZoneName = "MY TIME ZONE HERE";
$timeZone     = DateTime::TimeZone->new(name => $timeZoneName);
$timeNow      = time();
$dateTime     = DateTime->from_epoch(epoch => $timeNow);
$offset       = $timeZone->offset_for_datetime($dateTime);
$localTime    = $timeNow + $offset;
print "$localTime";
```

But I don't know how to look up local time with PHP, anyone help?

Comment: In Perl, one can simply do: `DateTime->now( time_zone => $timeZoneName )` or even `DateTime->now( time_zone => 'local' )`

Comment: No idea why this is tagged Perl, or why you used some cryptic code a PHP programmer might not be able to read instead of saying what you want.

Comment: so you need server time?

Comment: I have a list of time zone from my visitors, and I want to know their local time.

Comment: you cant get user timezone with php at least I don't know how. Maybe you can go with IP try to find location ant then guess timezone but easier would be let user choose timezone for himself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in PHP:

```
$timezone = 'Europe/London';  //perl: $timeZoneName = "MY TIME ZONE HERE";

$date = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone($timezone));

$localtime = $date->format('h:i:s a');

echo "Local time is $localtime.";
```

If you don't have PHP 5.2, see also [date_default_timezone_set()](http://php.net/date_default_timezone_set) or use `ini_set('date.timezone', $timezone);` and then PHP will operate as if it were in that timezone.  Any date you output will be in that of the given timezone.

[PHP Date/Time Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php) also have good references.  There are other ways you could do this in PHP but the above is simple and most servers should have PHP 5.2  or greater.

See [date()](http://php.net/date) for a list of formats you can pass to `DateTime::format` and also the [DateTime Class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) for references on other things you can do with `DateTime`.